Why are there fewer algorithms for continuous compared to discrete quantum computation?
Why are there significantly fewer algorithms for continuous quantum computation compared to discrete quantum computation?

Because they’re not universal. See this discussion for details.

@dimello I believe the OP (they will have to clarify, but based on tags) is referring to continuous variable QC, which is universal (given Gaussian operations plus a non-Gaussian resource). This is distinct from analog QC (annoyingly similar names)  or quantum annealing mentioned in the linked discussion.

There are a few reasons (and probably more I’m missing), but I’ll highlight some key ideas:

Time: The foundational paper on universal quantum computation with continuous variables (CVQC) was published in 1998. This was over a decade after Deutsch’s seminal paper on universal discrete-variable quantum computation. This lag in development meant CVQC started with a significant delay in algorithmic exploration, and research momentum has since been dominated by qubits.

Familiarity and Practicality: Qubits are conceptually more intuitive and easier to work with, as they align with our classical understanding of bits. Continuous variables, on the other hand, are more alien—partly because classical analog computing doesn’t work (by doesn't work, I mean it isn’t widely used in practice). One significant reason for this is that classical analog computers cannot perform error correction due to a no-go theorem: the continuous states are all equally valid, making it impossible to determine if an error has shifted a state.

Error Correction Challenges: Encoding physical continuous-variable quantum information into logical continuous-variable quantum information is significantly harder than with qubits. This stems from another no-go theorem, which states that Gaussian errors cannot be corrected using purely Gaussian quantum resources [1]. This is in contrast to discrete-variable error correction codes that can correct both Clifford and non-Clifford errors using only Clifford operations and measurements. One way to circumvent this for CVQC is to use GKP states as a non-Gaussian resource [2], encoding oscillators into many oscillators. However, oscillator-to-oscillator code families have been shown to lack a threshold under certain conditions [3], which complicates fault tolerance.


These points are by no means exhaustive and are somewhat opinionated, so others may view some of these factors differently. That said, there is growing interest in quantum algorithms for CVQC, e.g. simulating quantum chemistry, particle physics, or even hybrid CV-DV algorithms.
